# Prevent firebase automatic Signin after creating a new user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, signing

I was working on a project which has an admin side, an admin could add another admins, and when an **admin A** add an **admin B** it automatically signin the admin B, so after many researches I found that firebase doesn't provide any way to prevent or disable this behavior.

Comment: You should use the `Firebase Admin SDK` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on Firebase Cloud Functions or a self-hosted server in that case. Everything else would just be a dirty hack

Comment: While there are concerns with creating accounts for other users in the frontend, is there a reason you don't use a second background Auth instance to handle the sign up flow? This allows you to sign in Admin B and keep Admin A's session around to update your database with any needed info for the new account. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59812155/3068190) for details, modify the second block with `fbWorkerAuth` using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` instead and sign out the account when done. If needed, I can provide a modern namespaced SDK variant here.

Comment: @PRSHL If Everything else (doing all the work on the frontend) is dirty hack, can you please explain why there is the `Firebase javascript SDK` in the first place ? what is it used for ? only apps ?

Comment: @medosem fetching data from the database without heavy processing is fine by the Firebase Client SDK but in my opinion there are several cases like yours that should be handled entirely in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I wanted to find the best solutions for a perfect user interaction, as we say **features comes to fix bugs**, So here is my alternative solution to hide this 'bug' :

1. Before everything, we want to save our current admin's email in a state.
2. When we click the submit button, we create a new **admin B** like usual cases.
3. When **admin B** has been created successfully we open a dialog box and we ask **admin A** to confirm this action by providing his password (like a security check) on a password field inside the dialog box.
   4.Now we have all credentials of **admin A** as shown in step 1 (email) and step 3 (password).
   5.Now we can call signin method and sign the **admin A** back.
   Now let's write it in code (I'm using Rreact and @mui/material in my frontend) :

**Frontend :**

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="Email"
  type="email"
  onChange={(email)=>{setEmail(email.target.value)}}
/>
<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="Password"
  type="password"
  onChange={(pass)=>{setPassword(email.target.value)}}
/>
<Button
 onClick={createNewAdmin}
/>
<Dialog open={showDialog}>
  <DialogContent>
    <DialogContentText>
      Tap  your password !
    </DialogContentText>
    <TextField
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        onClick={(pass)=>setReAuthPass(pass.target.value)}}
      />
  </DialogContent>
  <DialogActions>
   <Button onClick={signAdminBack}>
    Confirm
   </Button>
  </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

**State :**

```
const[email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
const[password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
const[oldEmail, setOldEmail] = React.useState('');
const[reAuthPass, setReAuthPass] = React.useState('');
const[showDialog, setDialog]=React.useState(false);
```

**Functions :**

```
const createNewAdmin=()=>{
   const auth = getAuth();
      //saving the current admin email
      setOldEmail(auth.currentUser.email);
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
         //opening the dialog
         setDialog(true);
        }).catch((error)=>{console.log(error);});
}

const signAdminBack=()=>{
  const auth=getAuth();
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, oldEmail, reAuthPass).then((userCredential)=>{
          //admin A brought back
          //closing the dialog
        }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
        });

}
```

**Images**
[image]

[image: Bringing back the old admin]

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to create admin accounts on the front end as anyone could look into the code and action it themselves. You would want to create sufficient rules in the Firebase console to prevent users from editing other accounts etc. In fact, creating any new accounts but your own in the front end. This should all be controlled by Firebase's Authentication service.

If you want to create an admin account, create a cloud function to do that and then just call the cloud function. Something like this:

My cloud function - I use custom user claims to make someone an admin as opposed to saving a 'isAdmin' property in the user's document in firestore:

```
exports.addAdminRole = functions.region('your-region-here').https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (context.auth?.token.superAdmin !== true) { //-- Here it checks if the person making the call is an admin (or super admin) user
    return { error: 'Only super admins can add other admins.' }
  }
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => { // replace this getUserByEmail with creating a new user if needed
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      admin: true
    });
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      massage: `Success, ${data.email} has been made an admin.`
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
});
```

Then you can call this function from your app:

```
makeAdmin(adminEmail: string) {
    const callable = httpsCallable(this.functions, 'addAdminRole')
    callable({ email: adminEmail }).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
  }
```

Note that my example takes an existing user and makes them an admin, you can just replace the get user with create user and then set the customerUserClaim and even trigger an email at this point to them if you want to be fancy. Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got the perfect solution **(for vanilla JavaScript)**,

while creating the user itself you can use the **signOut(auth)** for preventing default signing in to the newly created user

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-app.js";

import {
getAuth,
createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
signOut,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-auth.js";

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app);

button.click(() => {
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, Password)
.then((res) => {
signOut(auth);
});
});
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back late, this solution only solves the problem in the case no one is already authenticated, but if anyone was authenticated it will log him out anyway!