# How can Firebase Authentication securely authenticate a user with only client-side code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

There is plenty of tutorials and articles on this precise question but each one contradict the previous one,
I'm trying to make a signup and login reactJs pages with `Firebase js sdk` on the frontend, that's what I found most of youtubers devs do,
And then I found that is not secure (doing the authentication on client side).

> You should use the Firebase Admin SDK (firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on Firebase Cloud Functions or a self-hosted server in that case. Everything else would just be a dirty hack – PRSHL [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158512/prevent-firebase-automatic-signin-after-creating-a-new-user?noredirect=1#comment129206966_73158512)

> It's not recommended to create admin accounts on the front end as anyone could look into the code and action it themselves. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73158643/17263804)

I really want to understand if it is not secure to use it on the client side, Why does firebase provided it in the first place ?? or is there another way to properly write the auth using `firebase js sdk` on the frontend ? of course without using `admin sdk`
Or should I use  `firebase js sdk` on the backend with express ?
I only want clear and detailed answers please !!

Comment: Firebase offers a client-side SDK for signing in, because it can do so securely. I provided an explanation of the process below. If you doubt whether that is secure based on some source, repeat the exact claim that source makes in your question and provide a link to it (so we can check for context). Without those there isn't much we can do to answer, and your question will likely get closed for being too broad (but may be reopened when you add the requested information).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This is the comment :   [You should use the Firebase Admin SDK (firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on Firebase Cloud Functions or a self-hosted server in that case. Everything else would just be a dirty hack – 
PRSHL]  Link : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158512/prevent-firebase-automatic-signin-after-creating-a-new-user?noredirect=1#comment129206966_73158512 ) and it's right there my auth code (don't focus on my question/solution it may not be the perfect way), just focus on that comment .

Comment: Please don't provide necessary information in comments, but instead edit your question (there's a link right under it for this purpose) to include this information and the link.

Comment: Of those two comments, the first one does not specify what operation they perceive as insecure - so it's hard to comment on. The second comment is correct and explains exactly what the risk is: "It's not recommended to create admin accounts  on the front end as anyone could look into the code and action it themselves" So while you can safely create a user account on the client, marking them as an admin has to happen in a secure environment as otherwise any user could make themselves an admin.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Does it make it more secure and less risky if only an admin can create an admin on the admin dashboard ?

Comment: That definitely helps, as long as the check for "is this an admin" does not only happen in the client - as then again anyone could claim to be an admin and make themsleves an admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you're confused between authenticating a user client-side and the fact that Firebase provides a client-side SDK for authenticating users.

Though all *you* have to do to use Firebase Authentication in your app is implement its client-side SDK, there are many more parts involved in the process - and quite a few of them run on secured servers.

It's just that Firebase (and the authentication providers it supports) have implemented the server-side of the authentication process for you already and made the variables parts of the process part of the configuration that you provide either in the Firebase console, the provider's web interface, and/or in the configuration that you specify when you initialize the Firebase SDK in your client-side application code.

---

From the comments you now added, the second is correct and explains exactly what the risk is:

> It's not recommended to create admin accounts  on the front end as anyone could look into the code and action it themselves.

So while you can safely create a user account on the client (a process known as authentication), marking them as an admin (a process known as authorization) has to happen in a trusted environment as otherwise any user could make themselves an admin.